# Good practice to run 'php artisan schedule:run' for Laravel in Kubernetes

Tags: php, laravel, kubernetes

I am working on integrating a few Laravel PHP applications into a new Kubernetes architecture, and still struggling on how I can run `php artisan schedule:run` in a nice manner.

In the official Laravel manual, we are advised to set up the cronjob like this.

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

ref. https://readouble.com/laravel/5.7/en/scheduling.html

**Cronjob**

Initially, I came up with the idea of using cronjob in Kubernetes, and it works fine for now but started worried about the current architecture.

(One deployment for web service, and one cronjob for the task scheduling.)

```
---
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: cron
  namespace: my-laravel-app
spec:
  concurrencyPolicy: Replace
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - image: my_laravel_app_image:latest
            name: cron
            command: ["php", "artisan", "schedule:run"]
            imagePullPolicy: Always
            envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: laravel-app-config
            - secretRef:
                name: laravel-app-secret
          restartPolicy: Never
```

However, since I use `concurrencyPolicy: Replace` here the pod itself might be terminated even the job is still running (for more than 1 minute). To avoid this issue, I could use the default value `concurrencyPolicy: Allow` but it introduces another issue - Even I set `failedJobsHistoryLimit` at 1 and `successfulJobsHistoryLimit` at 1 the pod associated with the job are not properly terminated in the current running in-house Kubernetes cluster, and it reaches quota limit.

```
NAME                        READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
pod/test-cronjob-a           0/1     Completed   0          4m30s
pod/test-cronjob-b           0/1     Completed   0          3m30s
pod/test-cronjob-c           0/1     Completed   0          2m29s
pod/test-cronjob-d           0/1     Completed   0          88s
pod/test-cronjob-e           0/1     Completed   0          28s
```

ref. https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/74741#issuecomment-712707783

Also, I feel It's a bit tricky to configure the monitoring and logging stack for those one-off jobs.

**Deployment**

Instead of using cronjob, I'm thinking to try to deploy the scheduler as another pod having the cron setting in the container using deployment resource.

(One deployment for web service, and one deployment for the task scheduling.)

**I just wonder how you guys normally work around this issue in a scalable manner.**

Comment: I am facing same issue is a disaster, one pod running up every minute then down. Creating so many logs, noise anywhere. I think I will just leave one instance 24/7 and with supervisor inside execute every minute the artisan command (did that before moving to kubernetes worked fine). It makes no sense imo to create/destroy pod for cron every minute too much effort, is same as keeping one instance 24/7 (pod) and run there every minute the cron, and do not register this in load balancer to serve requests.

Comment: We have the same issue here, we are thinking to move to a container instead of use Kubernetes Jobs with laravel, how did you solved it?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running `schedule:run` use K8s kind: Deployment (not Job) and run scheduler as a daemon:

```
php artisan schedule:work
```

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler-locally

More details:

See: https://medium.com/@agungdarmanto/how-to-run-a-laravel-application-into-kubernetes-a6d0111dc98d